# JAXB: choices in separate classes

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a XSD like the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="command">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:integer"/>
                                <xs:element name="aaa" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="bbb" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:integer"/>
                                <xs:element name="ccc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ddd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:choice>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

JAXB generates a generic content field, which is not very convenient:

```
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ddd", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "abc", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "bbb", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "aaa", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "bar", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "foo", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ccc", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> content;
```

I'd like to have 2 separate classes for the 2 sequences, containing the according properties.

Please note that I cannot change the XML structure. I'd prefer a custom binding solution (using a xjb file), but I might be able to change the XSD as well, as long as it doesn't change the XML structure.

Eg. I tried:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="command">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:group ref="AGroup"/>
                            <xs:group ref="BGroup"/>
                        </xs:choice>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:group name="AGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="aaa" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="BGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="bbb" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="abc" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="ccc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ddd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

but JAXB generates the same code.

Comment: Are you able to edit the POJOs?

Comment: @kirstyannelouise I want to generate the POJOs using the maven-jaxb2-plugin